# CanvasRenderer.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: THREE.RenderableVertex is not a constructor

Tags: three.js

CanvasRenderer.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: THREE.RenderableVertex is not a constructor

This error were in the CanvasRenderer.js,I searched for the answer for long ,well there's no similar quertion.I just want to see the difference between WebGLRenderer and CanvasRenderer,but I meet this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [`Projector.js` file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js), which is not in the main Three.js build. [`THREE.RenderableVertex` is defined in that file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js#L43) (no idea why).